# I have problems with installing sphinx search

Tags: search, centos, sphinx

I'm trying to install sphinx on my CentOs server.
First I tried to install it using the rpm server. I had some issues with starting the daemon so I decided to re install it.
After I uninstalled the rpm package I tried to reinstall using the tar file.

My commands were as following:

```
wget http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.0.1-beta.tar.gz
tar –xvzf sphinx-2.0.1-beta.tar.gz
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx
make
make install
```

After that I configured the sphinx.conf file and uploaded it back to
/usr/local/sphinx/etc and tried to run the indexer..

```
sudo -u sphinx indexer --all
```

But I keep getting

```
sudo: indexer: command not found
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it from /usr/local/sphinx/.  Type this at the command line:

```
sudo /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --all
```

If that works, then you've compiled and installed it correctly, but you need to figure out where to put your sphinx binaries on your system so that you can call them directly from the command line like you initially tried.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, but I just installed sphinx using a rpm file, and now everything works :)